# Ember CLI + Ember Data: How to Handle Error Messages

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to provide useful feedback for the user based on the response from the server when errors occur.  By default, Ember CLI provides a template for `error.hbs`, which sets its `model` to the `promise` returned from the Ember Data `GET` call.  I have configured error conditions on my template and would like to set those conditions in a controller:

```
{{#if pageNotFound}}
    <p>Sorry.  The page you requested does not exist.</p>
{{elseif internalServerError}}
    <p>An internal server error occured.  Please try again.</p>
{{elseif notAuthorized}}
    <p>It looks like you are not authorized to view this page.  Have you registered and logged in?</p>
{{/if}}
```

I have tried setting the values via my `ApplicationRoute` with no success, [as suggested here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-deal-with-route-when-model-gets-a-404/5283):

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
    actions:
        error: (error, transition) ->
            errorController = @controllerFor "error"
            switch error.status
                when 404 then errorController.set("pageNotFound", true)
                when 500 then errorController.set("internalServerError", true)
                when 403 then errorController.set("notAuthorized", true)
                else errorController.set("generic error", true)
            @transitionTo "error"
)
```

But I see no transition, though the actions function triggers when I put a `console.log` in.

How can I display conditional error messages based on the promise `status` value on a generic `ApplicationError` route and template?